# T-convex envelopes of double sequence spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Does anybody know if the t-convex envelope of the double sequence space $l^q(l^p)$ is $l^q(l^t)$ in the case $0 < p < t < 1 < q < \infty$? Also the same question is asked for $q = \infty$. If yes, can anyone point me in the direction of a proof?

It is supposed to be true when $l^q$ is replaced with $c_0$. That is the t-convex envelope of $c_0(l^p)$ is $c_0(l^t)$. This is stated without proof in a paper by C. Leranoz ; Uniqueness Of The Unconditional Basis Of $c_0(l^p)$, $0 < p < 1$ (Studia Math 102 (3) 1992)

More generally if $Y$ is the t-convex envelope of the quasi-Banach space $X$ is
$l^q(Y)$ the t-convex envelope for $l^q(X)$ when $q > 1$

Comment: What is the defintion of t-convex envelope?